# Excel interop macro out/ref parameters

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vb6

I have inherited a VB6 app that launches Excel, opens a workbook, and runs a macro on an interval. This macro returns values though its parameters. In my attempts to convert this to C# using interop, I can successfully run the macro, but these parameter values do not get returned.

Is there something missing/incorrect in the code below, or is this simply not supported?

VBA macro:

```
Sub Foo(bar As Long)
    bar = 5
End Sub
```

C# code:

```
void CallFoo()
{
    // Declared as an object to avoid losing the value in auto-boxing
    // The result is the same if declared as int
    Object bar = 0;

    m_application.Run(m_fooCommand, a);

    Console.WriteLine(a); // a is always 0
}
```

This (roughly) equivalent VB6 code gets the return value just fine.

```
Dim bar as Long
bar = 0
xlApp.Run "Test.xlsm!Foo", bar
MsgBox bar // prints 5
```

Comment: `Excel.Application.Run` doesn't even assign `ByRef` in VBA. Are you sure the VB6 code is doing what you think it's doing?

Comment: Yes, the vb6 app has been functioning for years

Comment: That wasn't the question.  The question was "are you sure the VB6 code is doing what you think it's doing".  Do you have access to the VB6 code to include in the question?  All I'm seeing is the VBA macro and the C# code you're using now.

Comment: If `a` was passed ByRef, then it would be `ref a` in C#

Comment: Unfortunately the parameters of Run() are not declared ref. At first I was kinda hoping interop would do some voodoo magic to make that work. But this seems not to be the case

Comment: If the `Run` parameters aren't `ByRef`, then the VB6 code can't possibly work the way you describe. *There is no magic*. At this point your question can't be answered without seeing the VB6 code.

Comment: Of course by magic, I simply mean hidden/under-the-hood mechanics. Similar to the way you new up an interface to instantiate the application object. The VB6 code certainly works as posted

Comment: Also , VB6 is default `ByRef`, It's the C# method signature that is not declared `ref`.

Comment: Can't the `Run` method return a value?  Just change the `Sub` to a `Function` instead.

Comment: Yes, it can return a single value. I guess I should have made it more clear in the example that the point is it can actually return multiple values that were originally returned by multiple parameters.

Comment: In the C#, object bar is declared but never  used?

Comment: Thanks, fixed. My foos and bars were getting away from me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as best as I can tell, no, you cannot return values through parameters from VBA to C# in this way. The next best thing is to simply create a type in .NET, make it COM visible, regasm it and then reference that in the VBA script.

So, for completeness...

A return type:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("097B5B52-C73B-4BD0-A540-802D0BC7C49F")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IFooResult
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("76B6BCBD-6F4D-4457-8A85-CDC48F4A7613")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class FooResult : IFooResult
{
    [DispId(1)]
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
}
```

Generate strong name (required by regasm)

```
sn -k FooLib.snk
```

Register the assembly

```
regasm FooLib.dll /tlb:FooLib.tlb /codebase
```

Then simply reference the library in the VBA project. It can now be passed as an argument and populated in the macro or created in and returned from the macro (I believe this would require cleanup on the .NET side, Marshal.ReleaseComObject()).